# Changing the selected item of an OptionMenu programmatically

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have defined a simple `OptionMenu` like

```
import Tkinter as tk

optionList = ('a', 'b', 'c')
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(optionList[0])
om = tk.OptionMenu(self, v, *optionList)
```

This list will appear with `a` as default which is fine. But there are also command buttons defined which eventually need to alter this to show another of the available options (say `b`). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already found a way to set a default value and change it. You have the `v` variable associated to that `OptionMenu` widget. If at any time you change the value of that variable again, it will update your widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
optionList = ('a', 'b', 'c')
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(optionList[0])  # Here is the initially selected value
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, v, *optionList)
om.pack()

v.set(optionList[2]) # This one will be the final selected value 
root.mainloop()
```