# Change menu option of passed widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This will work fine if I have to change value of option by giving the original reference of v variable

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
optionList = ('a', 'b', 'c')
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(optionList[0])  # Here is the initially selected value
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, v, *optionList)
om.pack()

v.set(optionList[2]) # This one will be the final selected value 
root.mainloop()
```

But the problem is when we try to get the element by widget.winfo_children() and set it's value as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
optionList = ('a', 'b', 'c')
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(optionList[0])  # Here is the initially selected value
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, v, *optionList)
om.pack()

v.set(optionList[2]) # This one will be the final selected value 

_list = root.winfo_children()
print(len(_list))
for item in _list :
    item.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Than it will give error as `AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'set'`

Reference code from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138026/changing-the-selected-item-of-an-optionmenu-programmatically)

Comment: Well, an OptionMenu does not have a method named `set`. In your loop, `item` will at some point be set to the option menu, and then you call set on it. Hence the error that `OptionMenu object has no attribute set`

Comment: Any alternative @Bryan Oakley ?

Comment: I think the question is pretty unclear in its current state.

Comment: I don't understand. Alternative to what? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with that loop. This isn't a tkinter problem per se, you simply can't call a method of an object if that object doesn't have a method. Why are you trying to call set on the optionmenu, and why are you doing it in a loop?